# How to refresh a sorting with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use this script function to refresh currently applied filters on a sheet.

```
function refreshFilter() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();

  if (filter) {
    const range = filter.getRange();
    for (let i = range.getColumn(), maxCol = range.getLastColumn(); i <= maxCol; i++) {
      const filterCriteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i);
      if (filterCriteria) {
        filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(i, filterCriteria);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to do the same for sorting as well?
I know about the `SORT()` function, but I need to do this from a script, not a built-in function.
I know there is `range.sort()` method, but I'm struggling to get the current sort spect using `getSortSpecs()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

In my experience, when I tested each method of Class SortSpec, an error like `Unexpected error` occurred. So, when I am required to refresh the basic filter including the sort, I use Sheets API instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) as a workaround.

When Sheets API is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function refreshFilter() {
  const sheetName = "Dashboard"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const { basicFilter } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [sheetName], fields: "sheets(basicFilter)" }).sheets[0];
  if (!basicFilter) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ setBasicFilter: { filter: basicFilter } }] }, ssId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the basic filter of "Dashboard" sheet is refreshed including the sort.
- In this case, the process cost is lower than that of the Spreadsheet service.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [SetBasicFilterRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#setbasicfilterrequest)

Comment: Looks like it works, thank you.
I will do more testing tomorrow.

Comment: The function works fine. But now I encountered another issue. I have a function that updates the data in a spreadsheet, and I want to refresh the filter/sorting after the data is updated. But if I call `refreshFilter()` at the end of my function that updates the data it doesn't work properly because `refreshFilter()` runs before the actual data is updated e.g. `IMPORTXML` takes 3-5 seconds to finish. But `refreshFilter()` runs right after it. So I'm trying to do something like `async/await` or a similar workaround.

Comment: @ihorc Thank you for replying. Now, I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I noticed your new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77944270 . And also, I noticed your new question was resolved. I'm glad for it.