# Execute a function after data import is finished

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function that updates the data in my spreadsheet.
Also, I have a function that refreshes currently applied filters/sorting.
But I can't make them work in order.
Sample code:

```
function updateData() {
  ...
  cell.setFormula("IMPORTJSON(\"" + myURL + "\", \"" + myXPATH + "\"");
  refreshFilter();
}
```

It sets the cell formula, but then `IMPORTXML` takes ~3-5s to update the data.
And `refreshFilter()` is executed while the data is still fetching, thus useless.

So I need some `async/await` behavior or a similar workaround.
Using `Utilities.sleep(x)` is not a solution as the fetch time might differ and is not guaranteed.

**upd.** `IMPORTJSON` is a custom function since there is no built-in function for importing JSON.

Comment: Why not use [`xmlservice`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) and thus end with the result of parsed xml, instead of the roundabout waiting or even event listening?

Comment: I'm using a custom function to import JSON, not XML.
I just added `IMPORTXML` for illustration, since they behave similarly. I will update the sample code to avoid confusion.

Comment: The edits are good to make. Your answer about flushing is also worth making as it is indeed relevant to the literal question. However, the same question about use case applies: why not directly read json within the script execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.
After some testing, I found that even if I add some significant delay to the `refreshFilter` function, the data **is only updated after the entire `updateData` function is finished**.
It means the cell's value is modified on time, but it waits for the function to finish before applying all changes.

So I tried adding [`SpreadsheetApp.flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) after setting the formula and it worked as expected. No manual delays are needed, and functions are executed in the order they are called.

```
function updateData() {
  ...
  cell.setFormula("IMPORTJSON(\"" + myURL + "\", \"" + myXPATH + "\"");
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  refreshFilter();
}
```